# Beginner's Objective-C Syntax Question

Tags: objective-c

I came across the following code snippets from Apple's Documentation.

The Interface is fairly straightforward:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ApplicationCell.h"

@interface CompositeSubviewBasedApplicationCell : ApplicationCell {
        UIView *cellContentView;
}
@end
```

The implementation:

```
#import "CompositeSubviewBasedApplicationCell.h"

@interface CompositeSubviewBasedApplicationCellContentView : UIView {
    ApplicationCell *_cell;
    BOOL _highlighted;
}

@end

@implementation CompositeSubviewBasedApplicationCellContentView
//not important, abbreviated...
@end
```

I can't quite figure out why there is another @interface declaration in the implementation file. I assume that it is a way of declaring private instance variable. Am I right?

And since the interface already said that `CompositeSubviewBasedApplicationCell` extends `ApplicationCell`, what does `CompositeSubviewBasedApplicationCellContentView : UIView` mean?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the definition of another class. In most cases, this would be in a separate file, but it's also possible to define multiple classes in one file, especially if they're closely related.

`CompositeSubviewBasedApplicationCellContentView` is probably not used by any classes except for `CompositeSubviewBasedApplicationCell`, so it doesn't need to have its own header file.

Comment: Oh my. I must be tired. I did not find that it's a different definition. Totally missed the "ContentView" in the end of the name. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

`CompositeSubviewBasedApplicationCell` and `CompositeSubviewBasedApplicationCellContentView` are two different classes.

> I can't quite figure out why there is another @interface declaration in the implementation file. I assume that it is a way of declaring private instance variable. Am I right?

Yes, that's a way to make a class completely private. If someone wanted it to be partially private they could just extend it in the implementation file like this:

```
@interface CompositeSubviewBasedApplicationCell()

@end
```